# Upload (.doc, .docx) file in php using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to upload a `.doc, .docx` file via ajax but it keeps on sending me an error in my console. Here is my script.

```
        var file = $('#file').val();
        $(document).on('change','#file',function(){
            var data = new FormData($("#fileinfo"));
            $.each($('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                data.append('file-'+i, file);
            });
            console.log(FormData);
            $.ajax({
                url: "main-function.php?call=upload",
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data)
                }
            });
            return false;

        });
```

And here is `main-function.php`:

```
   if ($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    die("Upload failed with error " . $_FILES['file']['error']);
    }
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $ok = false;
    $userid = $_SESSION['username'];
    switch ($mime) {       
       case 'application/pdf':
       case 'application/msword':
            $ok = true;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
              "pds/" . $userid . '-' . time().'-' . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
             break;
       default:
           echo 'Type not supported';
    }
```

Edit: Here is the error

```
  <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: file in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\hrms\main\main-function.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />

  <b>Warning</b>:  finfo_file() [<a href='function.finfo-file'>function.finfo-file</a>]: Empty filename or path in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\hrms\main\main-function.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
```

Comment: What error you are getting? ok with other file types?

Comment: What is `attr( "enctype", "multipart/form-data" ),`? And what error is it "sending" to your console?

Comment: I think it's because it doesn't include `multipart/form-data` in the `posted` data. That's why error occur. Thoughts? or Any alternative on uploading the file via `ajax` or `jquery`?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending files as `file-0`, `file-1`, ... but you are looking for `file`.
If you're only sending one file just send the file as `file`

```
data.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
```

also if `#fileinfo` a form, you'll want to pass it to FormData constructor not a jQuery object

```
var data = new FormData($("#fileinfo")[0]);
```

also if `#file` is in that form you'll be sending the file twice.